# Is it possible to use a PATA to SATA adapter in a notebook?

Tags: laptop, ssd, upgrade, pata

How to update an old notebook with a SATA SSD (that I already have)?

I know there are adapters available, but they apparently don't fit in a laptop because the dimensions of the SSD and PATA drive are the same.

Is it possible to use such an adapter with a notebook?

Gateway MT3705.

Answer (score 3):

No, or at least not easily.

Technically there are at least these three ways to use your current SSD in your notebook. Neither of them seem worth it.

- You will either need to use the convertor to convert the PATA signal to SATA, and use a cable (due to the lack of remaining space in the drive bay) to the SATA SSD somewhere in the laptop. That can work, but it is a kludge. Airflow  inside the laptop may be impeded. Not my preferred solution.
- Or use the convertor and a smaller SATA SSD. These do exist, but you wrote that you already have a (regular) SATA SSD. And if you would need to buy a new (smaller) SSD you might as well buy a PATA SSD. So technically an option, but not sensible in practise.
- Or use some soldering skills on a laptop board (*shudder*) to remove the PATA connector to another location. Essentially making more space near the drive bay. This is not something to do unless you are very good at soldering.

Comment: Someone has managed to pull off the first solution and cram the result in the drive bay. They used a very slim SATA-to-IDE board [taped to the bottom](http://forum.51nb.com/attachments/month_1111/20111106_a1d2bf15a566efe2fdafO6QtHdJLCOLr.jpg) of the drive and soldered the SATA connectors to it. Possible, but ... yuck.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's always interesting to watch kludge jobs not quite make it through the drop test.

Comment: @FiascoLabs - You making a habit of dropping your notebook/laptop?

Comment: No, but life happens. Good kludgers engineer for it.